# Transferring website likes to fanpage likes

Tags: facebook, like

as far as I understood Facebook also offers "likes" for plain websites without their own fanpage.

Now, if one has a certain number of such likes and decides to open a dedicated fanpage is there a way to transfer these "likes" to the fanpage or does he have to start from zero?

Thanks

Comment: Wouldn't that 'fanpage' be a separate entity than the 'plain website'? I think you'll have to start at zero, sorry. There are services where you can 'buy' likes. Not expanding on that any further, it's not something we support.

Comment: Do you know or believe that?

Comment: Well, yes. You can't transfer likes. You COULD, point the source of the LIKE button to your old page. `<fb:like href="http://www.facebook.com/pages/somethingy/old-ID/>`

Comment: You know that for sure? Your "wouldnt" didnt sound too convinced. My assumption would be that Facebook offers some migration way but just an assumption.

Comment: You can 'merge duplicates' but that doesn't always work; especially for pages with 100+ likes. But why don't you try what I suggested in my last comment, before criticizing it.

Comment: I wasnt criticising it at all :) - didnt just quite understand what you meant. How can I point it to an old page if I dont have one? The idea is to have first only website likes and then later maybe a fanpage and here I would like to migrate them naturally

Comment: If you're starting from scratch, why not just create the fanpage now if you're planning on going to that later? It would save you the trouble.

Comment: I am not sure yet, thats why. And if I could have migrated it it might have been a nice first way to start. But yes as it is a fanpage might be the best option. Thanks again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ionFish is right, you can't transfer those likes, what you want is like forcing all those users who liked your URL to subscribe to your Facebook page, that's technically and legally impossible.

But may I ask why do you need a fan page? how do you use likes on your website? do you use a single URL for all pages? or each page has it's own URL in like button?

By using some of the Facebook tools, you can make your website act like a Facebook page, for example you can use Facebook Comments on your site and when someone post a comment, they will share the story with others.

Anyway, if you want a Facebook page, make it sooner! tell on your website that you have a Facebook page now and invite all your friends to like your fan page too.

Yet, you want to keep that like button on your website to point to your website, for sure you know that each like to your website pages will create story, those likes could bring more visitors to your site than a story created from your Facebook page.

But if your website is not very active and you don't post many new pages each week, it might be better to point your like buttons on your site to your Facebook page, simply by replacing the URK in button's code.